# Ionic2 + Angularfire2 + Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have created an application with Ionic 2, which uses Firebase with email/passoword authentication. I'm using angularfire2 in order to talk to firebase.

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***********",
  authDomain: "***********",
  databaseURL: "*****************",
  storageBucket: "***************"
};

const myFirebaseAuthConfig = {
  provider: AuthProviders.Password,
  method: AuthMethods.Password
}

AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, myFirebaseAuthConfig)
```

Everything is working fine but now i have decided to add Facebook Login and i cant make it work!

Here are the steps which i'm following.
I have installed the facebook plugin and have correctly setup Facebook - Firebase for Facebook auth, added the platforms to facebook etc:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

Now the problem :
The official documentation from angularfire2 says to use this method in order to connect to firebase and authenticate facebook users:

```
facebookLogin(){
    Facebook.login(['email']).then( (response) => {
        let facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
            .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);

        **firebase**.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
        .then((success) => {
            console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });

    }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
}
```

If i try to setup firebase as well in my app, of course it crashes.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "************",
      authDomain: "************",
      databaseURL: "**************",
      storageBucket: "***************"
    })
```

If i try to use this method with angularfire2, it says that method signInWithCredential does not exists. How am i supposed to use angularfire2 in my app but use the firebase import in order to achieve the facebook login in firebase together?!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have sorted this already, but here is what I have used for the Facebook login, using angular 2.

```
doFbLogin() {
let permissions = new Array();
permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_education_history"];

this.facebook.login(permissions)
  .then((success) => {
    console.log("facebook Success response->" + JSON.stringify(success));
    this.facebook.api("/me?fields=id,name,email,gender,first_name,last_name", permissions).then((user) => {
      //console.log("user details" + JSON.stringify(user));
      console.log("access token-" + JSON.stringify(success.authResponse.accessToken));
      var provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(success.authResponse.accessToken);

      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Firebase -fb success: " + JSON.stringify(response));
          this.af.database.object('/users/' + response.uid).update({
            name: response.displayName,
            email: response.email,
            role: 'User'
          });
          localStorage.setItem('uid', response.uid);
          this.navCtrl.push("HomePage");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Firebase failure:--- " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });

    }),
      (error) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        console.log('FAcebook not responding!');

      }

  }, error => {
    console.log("FaceBook ERROR : ", JSON.stringify(error));
  })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remember to import the following in **app.module.ts** and your **login page**:

**import * as firebase from "firebase";**

and this:

**import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';**

Then:

```
this.facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
    .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      let firecreds = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(firecreds).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
```

**PS** :

Also, make your Facebook app in Facebook Developer public, that way it's easier to test.

Enter your package name for your app in Facebook Developer and **packagename.name.MainActivity**

I dont think you need to add any **Hash keys**